# Xcode 8 not logging autolayout constraints on conflicts

Tags: xcode, macos, autolayout

On macOS Sierra, Xcode 8 does not log the autolayout constraints that are causing conflicts. I only get

```
[Layout] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
<private>

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<private>
```

Does anyone know how to convince Xcode to show me the constraints that are causing the problem?

Comment: And now it just started working again and I have no idea why :'( I opened the storyboard file. Maybe that has something to do with it. I'm now unable to reproduce the error I described above.